# Загрузка фотографий

Tags: php, изображения, upload

Нужно сделать загрузку фотографий до объявления, но что бы вырезалось 2 превью `100х100` и `200х200` и стандартная фотка. Вот уменьшить фото могу, а вырезать нет. Нужно без всяких готовых в интернете классов, и, естественно, чтобы все это дело в бд писалось.

Таблица - db_c

```
фото 100х100 - c_p100
фото 200х200 - с_p200
фотка своего размера - c_photo
```

Answer (score 1):

[Вырезать](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php):

```
bool imagecopy ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h )
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, чтобы использовать эту функцию нужно ли устанавливать дополнительные модули в php.ini?

Comment: Билиотека [**GD**](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php)